# How to copy all certificates from Kubernetes on one server to Kubernetes on another one?

Tags: kubernetes, certificate

How to copy all certificates from Kubernetes on one server to Kubernetes 
 on another one?

How to export them?

Possible import step

```
kubectl create secret tls {{ .Release.Name }}-ingress-tls-secret  --key /tmp/tls.key --cert /tmp/tls.crt [--namespace namespace]
```

Which actions should be after import step?

I want to see same certs on another server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kubernetes store the certificate in the secret.

you can simply export the secret and import it on to new kubernetes cluster.

here is one example to export the secret locally

> kubectl get secret my-secret-name(secret name) --export -o yaml >
>   my-secret-name.yaml

`my-secret-name.yaml` file will be created

now on the new cluster, you can simply import the certificate using generated yaml file

> `kubectl apply -f my-secret-name.yaml -n namespace-name`

(if want to set in a specific namespace)

after importing the certificate you can simply use them in `ingress`.